# can two injectable (service.ts) communicate with each other in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular2-services, angular-components

can two services.ts files that are injectable can communicate with each other, for example, can one service call the function or method of another service file .
if yes then how this is possible nevertheless whats the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Two services can communicate with each other using "Injector" class.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from 'app/services/my.service';
```

Inject "Injector" object inside your constructor

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
```

Then call your service

```
var myService = this.injector.get(MyService);
myService.get();
```

Comment: can you please explain the concept ? why its different from when service communicate with component

Comment: You can't reference one service directly into another service because of a circular-dependency.

Comment: can you please explain this line...i mean why this thing....why we cant use
this.injector.get() directly 
var myService = this.injector.get(MyService);

Answer (score 0):

It appears you **cannot** have two services referencing each other via mutual constructor injection, e.g

```
@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
  constructor(private service2: Service2) {}
  method1() {
    ...
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
  constructor(private service1: Service2) {}
  method2() {
    ...
  }
}
```

When you use constructor parameter injection, you get this error

```
compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyService1: (?).
at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1689)
```

However, it can be done if both utilize the injector outside of the constructor

```
@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  method1() {
    return 'some value';
  }

  method1a() {
    const service2 = this.injector(Service2);
    service2.method2()
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  method2() {
    return 'another value';
  }

  method2a() {
    const service1 = this.injector(Service1);
    service1.method1()
  }
}
```

**Note**, I'd be very careful not to call methods that then call back to the same service, e.g

```
Service1.method1 calls Service2.method2
which then calls Service1.method1
which then calls Service2.method2
...
```

This may be hard to avoid when dealing with complicated logic.

The best approach is to split one of the services into two separate services, so they don't need to call each other.